# Salesforce field to have lower case only

Tags: custom-field

We have a custom field which our business team only wants it to have lower case characters.

So basically I am telling them we have 4 options:

1. Use a formula field to convert into lower case
2. Use a Trigger/process builder to convert
3. Use a validation rule to force users to enter lower case only
4. Write a lwc to auto-update into lower case when user typing

But there is one thing I am not 100% sure. Is there a built-in way to automatically update user input into lower case when typing? My understanding is no but need to confirm.

Comment: before save Flow; not sure why you need to auto-lowercase during typing as upon save, value will be coerced to lowercase. Users will just "learn" that lowercasing occurs.  For example, on an Email field, you can type in mixed case and upon save, SFDC lowercases it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to get SF to do this with just config.

So, I'd suggest 2 + 4. LWC on the frontend to make it clear to the user that their text is going to get lower-cased, and a trigger to enforce it on the server-side.

Definitely not Process Builder, maybe before-save Flow if they don't want Apex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Process Builder/ Flow to lowercase the input (via LOWER function), or validate (via REGEX) in a validation rule. No code is strictly necessary to get the desired effect in terms of saving to the database. There is no config- only way to make the client do what you want, though.